# Inserting utf8 characters in DB using Django

Tags: python, django, utf-8, django-views

In Django how to use unicode when inserting into DB

Example:

```
       name =request.POST["name"] //This may be in Chinese or any other lanuages
       usr = Users(name=name)
       usr.save()
```

The Python version that is used in Cent os is python 2.4.3 and mod python version is 1.2.1_p2-1

Comment: Have you tried this yet?

Comment: Yup..There is an error at usr.save(). Also i tried to do this using SafeUnicode.But the content wont get inserted into the DB.IS this to do something with my python version?

Comment: what kind of error? please paste it. Are you sure your database is set up for UTF8?

Comment: Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xA45\xB34\xE0\xH4\x0...' for column 'code' at row 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should check if your database has utf8 charset on table in which you are trying to insert.

for mysql

```
show create table TableName;
```

to change encoding

```
   alter table TableName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? If it's MySQL, make sure you follow the Django documentation on [creating UTF-8 compatible MySQL databases](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysqldb).

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode('some string') in order to send the string to DB in Unicode. You might have different settings for the DB, but this is not connected with Django.